# Running multiple times a python script from different threads using different gpus

Tags: python, parallel-processing, gpgpu, slurm

I have a code that I would like to be executed by several different threads and each thread should makes use of a gpu in my cluster.
What I do is then is call slurm with the script below that runs daemon.py

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --account XXX
#SBATCH --nodelist=node5
#SBATCH -p XXX
#SBATCH -o ./results/out.%t.%j.%N.txt
#SBATCH -e ./results/out.%t.%j.%N.err
#SBATCH -J JobA
#SBATCH --get-user-env
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-core=1
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:a16:3
#SBATCH --hint=multithread

export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
srun python -u daemon.py
```

*daemon.py* then takes care of launching a number of threads equal to the number of gpu's available and making sure that when one thread finishes, launches another one with a different set of parameters taken from a "pool" of parameters (the global list at the beginning).

```
import logging
import threading
import subprocess
import time
import sys

import torch
print("GPUS",torch.cuda.device_count())

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')

parameters = [
    (0,),
    (1,),
    (2,),
    (3,),
    (4,),
    (5,),
    (6,),
    (7,)
]

N_GPUS = 5  # Number of GPUs available

def launch_script(param):
    logging.info(f"Launching with: {param}")
    subprocess.run(["python3", "test.py"] + [str(arg) for arg in param])
    logging.info(f"The script using parameters {param} is ended")

def end_daemon():
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    logging.info("Closing daemon")
    exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    param_index = 0

    threads = list()
    for i in range(N_GPUS):
        if param_index >= len(parameters):
            end_daemon()
        arg = (i,)+parameter_combinations[param_index]
        x = threading.Thread(target=launch_script, args=(arg,))
        threads.append(x)
        param_index += 1
        x.start()

    while True:
        for thread in threads:
            if not thread.is_alive():
                if param_index >= len(parameters):
                    end_daemon()
                i = threads.index(thread)
                arg = (i,)+parameter_combinations[param_index]
                new_thread = threading.Thread(target=launch_script, args=(arg,))
                threads[i] = new_thread
                new_thread.start()
                param_index += 1

        time.sleep(1)
```

*test.py*

```
import sys
import time
import torch

print("Script:", sys.argv[0])
print("Args:", sys.argv[1:])

device = torch.device(f'cuda:{sys.argv[1][0]}')
print("dev:",device)
print("cuda available:",torch.cuda.is_available())
print("n dev:",torch.cuda.device_count())

time.sleep(10)
```

*output*:

```
3
2024-02-16 15:49:28,760 [INFO] Launching with: (0, 0)
2024-02-16 15:49:28,760 [INFO] Launching with: (1, 1)
2024-02-16 15:49:28,761 [INFO] Launching with: (2, 2)
2024-02-16 15:49:28,762 [INFO] Launching with: (3, 3)
2024-02-16 15:49:28,763 [INFO] Launching with: (4, 4)
Script: test.py
Args: ['0', '0']
dev: cuda:0
cuda available: True
n dev: 3
Script: test.py
Args: ['4', '4']
dev: cuda:4
cuda available: True
n dev: 3
Script: test.py
Args: ['3', '3']
dev: cuda:3
cuda available: True
n dev: 3
Script: test.py
Args: ['1', '1']
dev: cuda:1
cuda available: True
n dev: 3
Script: test.py
Args: ['2', '2']
dev: cuda:2
cuda available: True
n dev: 3
2024-02-16 15:49:45,783 [INFO] The script using parameters (3, 3) is ended
2024-02-16 15:49:45,824 [INFO] The script using parameters (1, 1) is ended
2024-02-16 15:49:45,845 [INFO] The script using parameters (0, 0) is ended
2024-02-16 15:49:45,865 [INFO] The script using parameters (4, 4) is ended
2024-02-16 15:49:45,943 [INFO] The script using parameters (2, 2) is ended
2024-02-16 15:49:46,765 [INFO] Launching with: (0, 5)
2024-02-16 15:49:46,766 [INFO] Launching with: (1, 6)
2024-02-16 15:49:46,766 [INFO] Launching with: (2, 7)
Script: test.py
Args: ['1', '6']
dev: cuda:1
cuda available: True
n dev: 3
Script: test.py
Args: ['0', '5']
dev: cuda:0
cuda available: True
n dev: 3
Script: test.py
Args: ['2', '7']
dev: cuda:2
cuda available: True
n dev: 3
2024-02-16 15:50:00,646 [INFO] The script using parameters (1, 6) is ended
2024-02-16 15:50:00,707 [INFO] The script using parameters (0, 5) is ended
2024-02-16 15:50:00,919 [INFO] The script using parameters (2, 7) is ended
2024-02-16 15:50:00,919 [INFO] Closing daemon
```

node configuration:

```
NodeName=node5 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=16
   CPUAlloc=2 CPUTot=64 CPULoad=0.09
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=gpu:a16:3
   NodeAddr=node5 NodeHostName=node5 Version=20.11.4
   OS=Linux 5.10.0-20-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.158-2 (2022-12-13)
   RealMemory=773432 AllocMem=773432 FreeMem=599855 Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=MIXED ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=X
   BootTime=2023-05-05T13:01:56 SlurmdStartTime=2023-10-03T17:10:05
   CfgTRES=cpu=64,mem=773432M,billing=64,gres/gpu=3
   AllocTRES=cpu=2,mem=773432M,gres/gpu=1
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
   Comment=(null)
```

The problem is that those a16 gpu's are supposed to be virtualized so it's like I'm supposed to see 12 (4x3) but I keep seeing only 3.  What am I doing wrong ?